# What is the correct verb for killing an animal for food?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is the correct verb for killing an animal for food?

Can it be "Slaughter" or "Butcher" or "Harvest" ?

I am looking for a verb a farmer would use.

For example: "I will "verb" two of my cows this year."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual word is [***slaughter***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slaughter) for the act of killing the animals; [***butcher***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/butcher) is normally used for taking the animal’s corpse and cleaning and cutting it up for use as food. The usages are related, and Dictionary.com, for example, uses ***butcher*** as part of the definition for ***slaughter***.

[***Harvest***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/harvest) generally refers to the gathering of deliberately-planted vegetation for use, but may refer to gathering large numbers of animals, as trawling for fish.

Comment: ..which is to say that the first two are probably what you want. 'harvest' for animals is rarer and feels very metaphorical and feels like you're talking about a full herd; it would sound weird if you said you 'harvested a single animal'